# Sulu CMS - Visiblity condition from underlying value of resource single selection

Tags: php, reactjs, sulu

I have three entities `Provision`, `Gatekeeper` and `Data`.

```php
class Provision {
    private Gatekeeper $keeper; // ManyToOne
    private Collection $points; // ManyToMany
}

class Gatekeeper {
    private int $id;
    private string $name;
    private bool $allowData;
}

class Data {
    private int $value;
}
```

All entities have REST-CRUD logic implemented. In order to edit the `Provision` entity I've added configurations to the `sulu_admin.yaml`:

```yaml
sulu_admin:
  field_type_options:
    selection:
      data_selection:
        default_type: 'list_overlay'
        resource_key: 'data'
        types:
          list_overlay:
            adapter: 'table'
            list_key: 'data'
            display_properties: ['value']
            icon: 'su-plus'
            label: 'app.data'
            overlay_title: 'app.action.select.data'
    single_selection:
      single_gatekeeper_selection:
        default_type: 'single_select'
        resource_key: 'gatekeepers'
        types:
          single_select:
            display_property: 'name'
            id_property: 'id'
            overlay_title: 'app.action.select.gatekeeper'
```

Now, in the form configuration file for `Provision` entities, I want to include a `visibleCondition` for the data list:

```xml
<form xmlns="http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template http://schemas.sulu.io/template/form-1.0.xsd">
    <key>provision_details</key>
    <properties>
        <property name="gatekeeper" type="single_gatekeeper_selection" mandatory="true">
            <meta>
                <title>app.gatekeeper</title>
            </meta>
        </property>
        <property name="data" type="data_selection" visibleCondition="!!gatekeeper && gatekeeper.allowData">
            <meta>
                <title>app.data</title>
            </meta>
        </property>
    </properties>
</form>
```

Is there any possibility to implement this behaviour? I've already tried adding a custom `ConditionDataProvider`, but the main problem is that the `visibleCondition` is evaluated at `Field`-level while the only place I could pull the required data from would be the `ResourceListStore` in the `SingleSelect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible you only have access to the **raw form data**. For a single selection the `gatekeeper` value contains only the `id` of the selected element. Not any data of the element behind this element.

All data you have access to it, you see in save (POST/PUT) request of the form.

The only thing which is possible would be using `resource_store_properties_to_request` to filter the result of your data_selection by the gatekeeper id, this requires that your data api need to keep the `gatekeeper` parameter in mind to filter by it:

```xml
    <properties>
        <property name="gatekeeper" type="single_gatekeeper_selection" mandatory="true">
            <meta>
                <title>app.gatekeeper</title>
            </meta>
        </property>

        <property name="data" type="data_selection">
            <meta>
                <title>app.data</title>
            </meta>

            <params>
                <param name="resource_store_properties_to_request" type="collection">
                    <param name="gatekeeper" value="gatekeeper"/>
                </param>
            </params>
        </property>
    </properties>
```